# How do you perform a rollback when using MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

With EF Migrations you can add migration scaffoldings and then keep running 'Update-Database' to apply changes. And in order to rollback the following works:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration: <xyzMigration>
```

This is great for updating your dev. DB. However when I automate migrations using MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion for deploying to other environments like test and prod. adding migration files for any changes and having them reflect works well.

But, in case I wanted to rollback to a specific migration how do I achieve that? 'Update-Database -TargetMigration:' only updates your local dev. DB or whatever your connection string is pointing to locally. And that has to be run via Package Manager Console. Is rollback not an option for actual deployments? Do you have to just 'Add-Migration' and specifiy a new migration that has all the changes you want reflected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a production database doing an `Add-Migration` with the changes you want would probably make the most sense, especially if you have multiple deployments.

Other options include:

- Using [`DbMigrator.Update()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829363(v=vs.113).aspx) with a parameter that indicates the target migration. (I'd probably use a separate build, just for this purpose...seems tricky to handle...especially when you add additional migrations in the future).
- `Update-Database` also has optional arguments for `-ConnectionString`, but that would require setting up Visual Studio on a machine with access to the database you're targeting.